# htaccess redirect url with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have hundreds of links like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?tag=value
```

I want to redirect all links to

```
http://www.domain.com/value/
```

Example:

Link1 `http://www.domain.com/index.php?tag=LW1fdX49tR`
redirect to: `http://www.domain.com/LW1fdX49tR/`

Link2 `http://www.domain.com/index.php?tag=A3kh0QLIrc`
redirect to: `http://www.domain.com/A3kh0QLIrc/`

Link3 `http://www.domain.com/index.php?tag=vXwNR4U9qY`
redirect to: `http://www.domain.com/vXwNR4U9qY/`

etc

How can I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides redirecting the request, you probably want to make sure the new url actually works too. You'll need both an external redirect and an internal rewrite for that. In the example below I use the THE_REQUEST trick to only trigger the rule if it is the actual request url, not if it is rewritten internally. It is required to prevent an infinite loop.

```
#External redirect with THE_REQUEST trick; change R to R=301 when everything works correctly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?tag=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Comment: the new link looks like: `http://www.domain.com/value.php?tag=value` and i need to be `http://www.domain.com/value/`

Comment: Yes, and? What problem do you have to adjust the answer to work for that case?

Comment: can you take a look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385741/permanent-redirect-with-parameters) here?