# Htaccess rewrites: I want to first redirect urls to new form then use RewriteUrl for these

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have my urls structured like this:

```
example.com/show.php?ctg=1&entry=some-entry-string
```

Since I want to switch to using new form:

```
example.com/some-entry-string.html
```

what is the way to go, provided that I have to stick with my current application code?

That being said, I want to old urls be permanently (301) redirected to the new form, and then, until my app code is rewritten, I'd be using the following (of course, my links in the app would be adjusted to the new form):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /show.php?ctg=1&entry=$1 [L]
```

The above line works as expected - every request in the new form gets properly rewritten so my app is able to handle it and display proper content. I have tried many options to achieve what is said at the top of this question but to no avail.

Comment: What is your question? Narrow down your title.

Comment: The question is how to redirect the first example to the second url example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below **should** would

```
RewriteEngine On

#External redirect with THE_REQUEST trick; change R to R=301 when everything works correctly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /show\.php\?ctg=1&tag=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2\.html? [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /show.php?ctg=1&tag=$1 [L]
```

(The above was adapted from another answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22568038/3204827))