# Redirect one page to another with parameters via htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect from a page to another with parameters with htaccess.

**For example:**

**From:** `www.websitename.co.uk/mylink.php?u=*username*`
**To:** `www.websitename.co.uk/mylink/*username*`

I tried this but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule www.websitename.co.uk/mylink.php?u=*username* www.websitename.co.uk/mylink/*username* [R=301]
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: possibly you require this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567357/htaccess-redirect-url-with-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite rules use regex like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/mylink.php?u=(.*) /mylink/$1 [R=301]
```

Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Working fine for me , hope this will work fine.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mylink\.php$   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} u=([a-zA-Z]+)
RewriteRule .* http://websitename.co.uk/mylink/%1? [R=301]
```