# Permanent Redirect with Parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

**Is there any way to permanently redirect a domain to another domain with a corresponding parameter?**

For example, somebody visits `example.com`, which permanently redirects to `eg.com/?url=example`.

I've tried `RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/eg\.com\/?url=example" [R=301,L]`, and, although it does indeed redirect to `eg.com`, it obviously ignores the parameters.

Is there any way to do this with `htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape backslash before question mark.

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/eg\.com\/\?url=example" [R=301,L]
#                                     ^ add backslash here
```

Comment: perfect. thanks a lot buddy. its been a while since ive written `mod-write` stuff

Comment: is there any way to preserve any preexisting parameters, instead of rewriting over them?

Comment: Yep, to flags add `QSA`, thats mean: `[R=301,L,QSA]`, learn more: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa